# How to get python's multiprocessing array'pointer and pass it to Cpp program?

Tags: python-multiprocessing, ctypes

I now need to request arrays in python, and pass them into a Cpp program, yet python still needs to process them. But I found that when I use multiprocessing, the array's adderess would be changed.

Below are my codes:

```
//export dll in test.h, this is test.cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void someWork(double* data, long* flag){
    cout << "cpp flag address:" << flag << endl;
    //do some work
}
```

```py
# test.py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
import ctypes

data = RawArray(ctypes.c_double, 2000)
flag = RawArray(ctypes.c_long, 20)
pkg = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"test.dll")
pkg.someWork.argtypes = [
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 2000),# dataArray
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long * 20)#flagArray
]

def proc_py():
    idx = 0
    while True:
        if flag[idx] == 1:
            # do something
            flag[idx] = 0
            idx = (idx + 1) % 20

def proc_cpp():
    pkg.someWork(ctypes.pointer(data), ctypes.pointer(flag))

def main():
    p_cpp = mp.Process(target=proc_cpp, args=())
    p_py = mp.Process(target=proc_py, args=())
    p_cpp .start()
    p_py .start()
    p_cpp .join()
    p_py .join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("py flag address:", ctypes.byref(flag))
    # proc_cpp()
    main()
```

The result is: when I just run `proc_cpp` in python, the address are the same:

```
py flag address: <cparam 'P' (0000019DA8282400)>
cpp flag address:   0000019DA8282400
```

But when I run `main`, the address are different:

```
py flag address: <cparam 'P' (000001CB42A32400)>
cpp flag address:   0000012F1E152400
```

I know that python's multiprocessing must use shared memory to share memory between processings, but I failed both by using `mp.Array`/`Array.get_obj()` and `mp.sharedctypes.RawArray`/`ctypes.pointer()`. Is there any way to solve my question?

Comment: Shared memory isn't necessarily mapped to the same virtual address in different processes.  Don't expect the addresses to match.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for your reply, but  it seems that if I want to pass array to c/cpp programs, I must pass pointer. Is there any advice to meet the request that c/cpp and python can use shared array in a multiprocessing task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create the `RawArray` outside of the "run once" main code or you are making *different* arrays.  Create the `RawArray` once in the main process, and pass that `RawArray` as a parameter to the target function of the new processes.  The virtual address each process "sees" will be different, but the physical memory will be the same.

Here's an example:

**test.cpp:**

This will display the pointer address and then change the specified index in the shared array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" API
void set(double* data, int index, double value) {
    cout << data << ' ' << index << ' ' << value << endl;
    data[index] = value;
}
```

**test.py:**

This passes the shared array to each process.  The main process will also change an element.  The lock is used because RawArray is not synchronized and the printing in the C++ code will mess up otherwise, so this code won't really run in parallel but it does illustrate that the processes get different virtual addresses but share the same data.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.set.argtypes = POINTER(c_double),c_int,c_double
dll.set.restype = None

def call(lock,data,index,value):
    with lock:
        dll.set(data,index,value)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # This code runs once in the main process.
    # The lock and shared data are created once only and passed to other processes.

    lock = mp.Lock()
    data = RawArray(c_double, 3)
    data[0] = 0.5
    p1 = mp.Process(target=call, args=(lock,data,1,1.25))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=call, args=(lock,data,2,2.5))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print(list(data))
```

Output (different addresses, same shared data):

```
00000269D66E0000 1 1.25
00000187F0B90000 2 2.5
[0.5, 1.25, 2.5]
```

Comment: I thought py must pass `ctypes.byref` or `ctypes.pointer`to pass arryay when calling cpp program, but didn't know it could directly pass python array. This answer is very useful, thank you!

Comment: @ChuangMen it imitates C’s passing of array decays to pointer. `ctypes` knows the correct type from `.argtypes` definition.