# Can Python call C++ DLL libraries compiled using extern "C" with ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

There are many articles on the internet that say that Python cannot access C++ compiled DLLs using **ctypes**, and there are other contradictory articles which say that it is possible to access the DLL so long as the DLL is compiled with the **extern "C"** method. So I just want clarification. Is it possible if  extern "C"  is used ?

Comment: Yes, of course. They look the same as C DLLs

Comment: I have done exactly this, on a LINUX platform, using this info: https://nesi.github.io/perf-training/python-scatter/ctypes.  I have never tried it on a Windows platform.

Comment: *Python cannot access C++ compiled DLLs using ctypes* -- This is not true, as the open source product I maintain (a C++ compiled DLL) is easily accessible using python.

Comment: Sure, for example, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528026/235698

Answer (score 3):

There are C++-compiled dlls which can be used with `ctypes` and C++-compiled dlls which cannot be used with `ctypes` directly.

If API exposes only [plain-old-data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/146452/5769463) (e.g. `int`, `int *`, `char *` and similar) and is wrapped in `extern "C"` then it can be consumed from `ctypes`.

If non-POD-classes are used (for example `std::vector` or `std::string`) in interfaces or the API isn't wrapped in  `extern "C"` then the dll cannot be used with `ctypes` (at least in a portable way and without much ado).

---

**Why `extern "C"` is needed?**

Following declarations are valid in C++ but not in C:

```
void my_fun(int a);
void my_fun(double a);
```

Because C doesn't perform name mangling, both functions would be mapped to a symbol named `my_fun` in the resulting object file, which is problematic.

C++ would create two different symbols with mangled names, for example gcc would create symbols `Z6my_funi` and `_Z6my_fund`. MSVC has another naming scheme - so the resulting symbols in the dll (or shared object) depends on the compiler with which it was built.

It is not impossible to find these symbols in the dll with help of `ctypes` - it is only not as straight forward as with C-names because one needs additional information - with which compiler the dll was build.

C-names work out of the box with `ctypes`, and wrapping declarations into `extern "C"` switches the name mangling off, thus

```
extern "C" {
  void my_fun(int a);
  void my_fun(double a);
}
```

would no longer compile, as compiler will ensure that there are no multiple definitions of a symbol.

**Why more complicated C++-classes cannot be used in interfaces?**

`extern "C"` doesn't forbid usage of `std::vector<>` and other C++-classes:

```
extern "C" {
  void my_fun(std::vector<double> a);
}
```

compiles, it only produces symbol `my_func` instead of `?my_fun@@YANV?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@@Z` (with MSVC) or `_Z6my_funSt6vectorIdSaIdEE` (with gcc) in the resulting object file.

While for PODs, let's say `double[10]`, the memory layout is clear, the memory layout of e.g. a `std::vector` is implementation dependent and is not known to `ctypes`. Another issue are  - something `ctypes` doesn't handle as well - constructors/destructors which can be more complicated than simple initialization of PODs.

Thus the functionality of `my_fun(std::vector<double>)` cannot be used out-of-the-box with `ctypes`. However, if one knows the memory layout of the classes, one could emulate them with `ctypes`, initialize objects by calling ([right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921467/5769463)) constructors (btw. symbols of class-methods are always mangled, even if wrapped in `extern "C"`), call the function `my_fun` and then destroy objects by calling (right) destructors.

Comment: So,  std::vector  and std::string  and the like are the only classes incompatible with ctypes?

Comment: @RobertTattorn It is the other way around: only PODs are compatible and nothing else.