# Errod with using ctypes in Python 3.6 for std::vector type

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I am trying to call C-function from Python by using ctypes features. And I got the error `TypeError: _argtypes_ must be a sequence of types`.

I am a bit confused how I can put `std::vector` in input.

So what I have - C file test.cpp that I compiled with `g++ -shared -o test.so -fPIC test.cpp`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C"{
    void test_func(std::vector<float> v){
        printf("%f\n", v.size());
        for(register int i = 0; i<v.size();++i){
            printf("%f\n", v[i] );
        }
        return;
    };
}
```

and Python-code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import ctypes as ct

def _np_ptr(np_array):
    return ct.c_void_p(np_array.ctypes.data)

lib = ct.CDLL('test.so' )
pfun = lib.test_func

v = np.array([1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,999], dtype=np.float32)



pfun.argtypes = ct.c_void_p
pfun.restype = None
pfun(_np_ptr(v))
```

I treied to combine `pfun.argtypes = [ct.c_void_p]`, `pfun.argtypes = ct.POINTER(ct.c_float)`, tried to call `pfun(ct.POINTER(v))`, nothing helped.

I will be very thankful for any correction and advice.

Comment: First thing first, know the name of the language you are using. It's called C++, not C. The library OTOH is called `ctypes`, and not `c++types`, and that's for a good reason. Python has no idea about `std::vector` or anything like that. `np_array.ctypes.data` is a C array.

Comment: If you want to call C++ functions using C++ types from Python, start reading [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) documentation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., ok, thank for this correction. So it is no way to call C++ function from Python as we can do for C-function (by ctypes)?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., thanks!

Comment: You can call a C++ function from Python with ctypes if you can call the same function from C.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., to be honest, I am not sure I can get what you mean. Can you give any detailed explonation?

Comment: A C++ function that uses parameter types not available in C cannot be called from C. Do we have `std::vector` in C? Don't think so. If your `test_func` accepted a `float*` instead, it would be callable from C.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., ok, got it,thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63688553/5769463

Comment: `extern "C"` is not C code but C++ code.