# Python C++ ctypes passing bool in ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error, ctypes

I'm trying to link my Python (3.7.6) code to C++ with a pass-back of a boolean from the C++ code to Python.  My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.  The IDE for the C++ is Visual Studio.

On running the Python wrapper code, I receive the message:

```
libcppstring.so: undefined symbol: cpp_string
```

The python code, the *.so file, etc. are all in the same directory.  The c++ code was compiled at the terminal prompt with

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -Werror -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC -o libcppstring.so cpp_string.cpp
```

My python wrapper code, c++ code, and the header code are very simple.  Just want to pass two strings from Python to C++ shared object and return 'true' to Python.  Perhaps I have messed up the order of the compile commands.

```
#---------python wrapper code------------------
import ctypes
import sys
import os
localPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(localPath)
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Load the shared library into c types.

    c_lib = ctypes.CDLL(localPath+"/libcppstring.so")

    # Sample data for our call:
    string1 = "hello, "
    string2 = "world"

    c_lib.cpp_string.restype = ctypes.c_bool
    answer = c_lib.cpp_string( string1, string2)

    print(answer)
```

---

cpp code: cpp_string.cpp

```
#include "cpp_string.h"

bool cpp_string( std::string string1, std::string string2){
    /*use this to convert to const char* to use sqlite3 in c */
    /*used once the code is working*/  
    string1.c_str();
    return (true);
}
```

header code: cpp_string.h

```
#include <string>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define EXPORT_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define EXPORT_SYMBOL
#endif

EXPORT_SYMBOL bool cpp_string( std::string string1, std::string string2);
```

Comment: ctypes is called ctypes and not c++types for a reason. Stick to C types, or use something other than ctypes.

Comment: Looks like the name of `cpp_string` was changed in the binary because of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++). Also, you set `c_lib.cpp_string.restype = ctypes.c_bool`, but what are the types of the _arguments_?? `std::string` isn't really a pointer to `char`, is it?

Comment: Hi, and thank you.  First, I should have used C types; there's a space in the title between c++ and ctypes.  Second, I'm not sure what's meant by name-mangling.  I intend later to compare the input strings from Python with two strings in the C++ code, and return 'true' if both pairs of strings match.  The std::string will be used with SQlite3, which accepts C-code chars.

Comment: Removed all instances of _ symbol from code names and uses.  Should address name-mangling issue.  Still receive same error: libcppstring.so: undefined symbol: cppstring.

Comment: You need to declare your function as `extern "C"`, and better make it return  `void` or `int` because C `bool` and C++ `bool` are not necessarily the same

Comment: You cannot use std::string with c types, even if you use extern C. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/63688553/5769463

Answer (score 0):

To interface `ctypes` with C++, use `extern "C"` functions with C-compatible types.  Also declare `.argtypes` (argument types and `.restype` (return type) for better error checking.

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

extern "C" API
int cpp_string(const char* string1, const char* string2) {
    std::cout << string1 << std::endl << string2 << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.cpp_string.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,ct.c_char_p
dll.cpp_string.restype = ct.c_int

print(dll.cpp_string(b'Hello',b'World!'))
```

Output:

```
Hello
World!
1
```

Note that `char*` in C is `c_char_p` in Python and takes Python `bytes` type parameters.  If you want to pass Python `str` type parameters, use `wchar_t*` / `c_wchar_p`.

Answer (score -2):

First, thanks very much to Mr. Tolonen.  From another community and a very helpful individual (all credit > J*M#), I did solve my problem.  Here's my code (all I wanted was the return of TRUE, which it does.

cppstring.h

```
#include <string>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define EXPORT_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define EXPORT_SYMBOL
#endif

extern "C" {
EXPORT_SYMBOL bool cppstring( std::string string1, std::string string2);
}
```

cppstring.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "cppstring.h"
bool cppstring( std::string string1, std::string string2){
/*use this to convert to const char* to use sqlite3 in c */
    string1.c_str();
    return (true);
}
```

and,

cString_test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" Simple examples of calling C functions through ctypes module. """
import ctypes
import sys
import os

localPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

sys.path.append(localPath)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load the shared library into c types.

    c_lib = ctypes.CDLL(localPath+"/libcppstring.so")

    # Sample data for our call:
    string1 = "hello, "
    string2 = "world"
    c_lib.cppstring.restype = ctypes.c_bool
    answer = c_lib.cppstring( string1, string2)
    print(answer)
```

Comment: This won't work for passing the strings to the C code.  Try to print them out.