# Python ctypes issue with DLL exports that return a const integer

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to call a function exported by a system DLL (to control battery charging of my laptop through a Python script).

To do so, I looked into ctypes and retrieved the decorated exported functions, this works for *some* exports but not for those that return a const int type.

**Code & Examples**

```py
from ctypes import CDLL, c_int

dllPath = "C:\\ProgramData\\Lenovo\\ImController\\Plugins\\IdeaNotebookPlugin\\x64\\PowerBattery.dll"
dll = CDLL(dllPath)

# Works
# Function: public: int __cdecl PowerBattery::CBatteryInformation::GetBatteryCount(void) __ptr64
GetBatteryCount = dll['?GetBatteryCount@CBatteryInformation@PowerBattery@@QEAAHXZ']
GetBatteryCount.argtypes = ()
GetBatteryCount.restype = c_int
print(GetBatteryCount()) # Returns "1" correctly

# Does not work
# Function: public: int __cdecl PowerBattery::CChargingMode::GetChargingMode(void)const __ptr64 
GetChargingMode = dll['?GetChargingMode@CChargingMode@PowerBattery@@QEBAHXZ']
GetChargingMode.argtypes = ()
GetChargingMode.restype = c_int

print(GetChargingMode())
# Exception access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

The difference between the two (to the best of my knowledge) is just the **const** type. How would I get the function to work?

Edit: please be advised that I do not control the DLL and cannot make changes on the C end.

Comment: Classes need a (hidden) class instance pointer as first argument, so I would say you're lucky the first example didn't crash.

Comment: @ssbssa thanks for your comment, would you be able to give me an example of that? I'm not familiar with c, and this is my first time using DLLs with Python. Or point me in the right direction?

Comment: But that's just it, if it were simple C functions, this would work. But you're trying to call C++ class member functions directly, that is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I've searched for a while now but cannot find a good example of how to implement this, do you have any leads for me? @ssbssa

Comment: If you don't know how to create the needed class instances, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Your dll is written in C++. there is a reason it is called `ctypes` and not `c++types`. There is a subset of C++-dll which could be used with ctypes (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/63688553/5769463). In your case you need at very least know the memory layout of `PowerBattery::CBatteryInformation`.

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html.